# Javascript check if one radio button is selected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to check that a user select at least one radio button. When clicking on the checkbox called mallname, I need to check if one of the payment radioboxes were checked.

Here is my HTML for payment (I need to check if one of these two are checked)

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Payment method</legend>
<div class='container'>
<label for='payment' >Please select payment method.:</label>
<p>
<label for='payment' >Once off (Full Payment):</label> 
<input type='radio' name='payment' id='paymentoo' onClick="SetHTML2('once')" value="Once off (Full Payment)" required <?php echo($isOnceoffFullPayment?'checked="checked"':''); ?> maxlength="50" />
<span id='register_payment_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<label for='payment' >Monthly Debit:</label>
<input type='radio' name='payment' id='paymentmd' onClick="SetHTML2('montly')" value="Monthly Debit" required <?php echo($isMonthlyDebit?'checked="checked"':''); ?> maxlength="50" />
<span id='register_payment_errorloc' class='error'></span>
<br>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

HTML for checkbox

```
<td width='400'><label for='contract' >$malls</label></td><td width='100'><input type='checkbox' name='mallname[]' id='mallname' value='$malls' onclick = 'checkpayment(); addemupfull(); addemupfulldebit();'/></td>
```

Here is my java

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkpayment(){
var payoo = document.getElementById("paymentoo");
var paymd = document.getElementById("paymentmd");
if(!(payoo || paymd).checked){
var malchecks = document.getElementById("mallname");
malchecks.checked = false;
alert("Please select a payment method first");
}
}
</script>
```

It works when 'paymentoo' is selected, but when 'paymentmd' is selected I still get the alert "Please select a payment method first"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`!(payoo || paymd).checked` will only check whether `payoo` is checked as the logical OR operator will return the first truthy value - since `payoo` is a dom element it will always return that

You need to check

```
if (!payoo.checked && !paymd.checked) {// if (!(payoo.checked || paymd.checked)) {
    var malchecks = document.getElementById("mallname");
    malchecks.checked = false;
    alert("Please select a payment method first");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is with this statement `(payoo || paymd)` - because `payoo` will always exist, all you are checking is whether `payoo` is checked. What you need is:

```
if(!(payoo.checked || paymd.checked)))
```

Or, an even faster way could be:

```
if(document.querySelectorAll('#paymentoo:checked, #paymentmd:checked').length)
```

Comment: Thanks. Great answer. I can only upvote 1 answer. I am going to be fair and upvote the first answer. Both answers helped me a lot.

Comment: Actually you can upvote both answers ;) Anyhow, the other answer has a better description of the `||` operator, so I'd go for that one as the right one anyhow. Good luck!